# Boot Ubuntu ISO under qemu

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

Probably a very simple issue: I'm trying to boot the offical Ubuntu 20.04.2 ISO image under qemu. For this purpose I've first created a disk image:

```
qemu-img create ubuntu-20.04.2.0.img 10G
```

And then tried:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -hda ubuntu-20.04.2.0.img -cdrom ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso -boot d -m 512
```

Which results in a kernel panic because "no working init" was found. I've encountered this issue before when trying to boot an image for the wrong architecture but I don't see what the problem is here.

Comment: You seem to not know much about virtual machines, please use the `virt-manager` frontend so it'll easier for you. It'll make KVM/QEMU look like VirtualBox.

Comment: @X.LINK Okay buddy, whatever you say.

Comment: Wow, did I touch a nerve ? Not spotting that you put 512MB of RAM on a VM and still wondering why Ubuntu 20.04.2 with the hoggy Gnome which uses more than 1.3 GB of RAM rang a bell that you would better use a GUI.

Comment: @X.LINK It's been at least five years since I've last booted Ubuntu, virtualized or otherwise, no reason to leave a rude comment like that...

Comment: My initial comment wasn't rude, but you assumed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you’re giving the VM too little memory: try `-m 4096` instead of `-m 512`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `qemu-system-x86_64 -hda confImage -m 1024`?